# Accessing Embedded Files in Embedded DLL

Tags: c#, vb.net, embedded-resource

I seem to be missing the trick to get access to files embedded inside a DLL that is an embedded resource of my app.

I know I can get to resources embedded directly in my app via

```
With Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly
    Debug.Print(Join(.GetManifestResourceNames, Environment.NewLine))
End With
```

... which lists the embedded DLL but doesn't list anything embedded in the DLL.

Put another way, the thing I want is double-embedded, for lack of a better term.

Hierarchy:

```
My EXE
    - Embedded DLL
        - Embedded file I want
```

**I'll gladly accept suggestions in C# or VB.**

Comment: Is the embedded dll a .Net Dll that you either plan to or already have loaded into the current AppDomain?

Comment: @erdomke yes...I control all the code, and all parts are .Net except the embedded content file I'm digging for.